# C# Convert Data using division or another method

Tags: c#, csv, charts, oledbdatareader

My code below is reading from a CSV file.  DataBindXY grabs a date for the X axis and then an int (actually the TYPE is General in the csv file).  I need to divide the Y value by 10 to create a decimal.  I've spent many hours and not quite sure how to complete.  It is important this value converts for my graph.  Unfortunately, the PLC programmer was unable to get the decimal value to output from our controller to the CSV so its up to me to convert it at this point when generating the graph.

```
// Create a database command on the connection using query
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + file;
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

// Open the connection and create the reader
myCommand.Connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

// Column 1 is a time value, column 2 is a int
// databind the reader to the chart using the DataBindXY method

chart_pH.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "2", myReader, "10" );
```

Comment: As you're reading from a text file, do you actually need the data to be bound?

Have you considered reading the data into variables, manipulating those variables (divide by 10), then plotting them?

Comment: I was hoping to do the calculation for the myReader (y-axis) value within that line of code.  Its the only data I need to convert to a decimal value.  I don't think there is a way so I'm guessing I will need to assign it to a variable.  If you have any suggestions on assigning to a variable that would be appreciated.  I thinking to create a class with all the data points but this would be more time consuming and more code.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Are you even sure what datatypes are returned? Do yourself a favor and make sure it really is a DateTime value or else the chart will not work well.. If you need to do a calculation on the 2nd value, store them in a DataTable and do it there..

Comment: X-axis is a time value and the y-axis would be a decimal value after calculation.  For example the data would be a 69 currently for the y axis value but actually need to read 6.9 once I graphed it out.  It is a pH measurement.